# Customize Rotation Behavior For Specific Widgets In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my Flutter Application, I am using a `OrientationBuilder` widget to change my layout based on the current orientation.

But the animation occuring when the widgets change position doesn't look smooth, and the scaling on UI elements temporarely becomes weird.

Is there a way to implement an orientation change, such that the elements just stay in their positions, and rotate themselves?

**Current behavior:**

[image: Current Behavior]

**Preferred Behavior:**

[image: Preferred Behavior]

I have left out the camera screen in the flutter App, as this is only about the onscreen controlls. The camera view itself isn't the issue!

Comment: have you thought about animating the rotation using a tween and timer controller?

Comment: How about just changing the rotation of the components and not the entire screen? You can set the rotation to portrait default, and then update the widgets when a change in rotation is detected

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Once I lock the orientation (at least using SystemChrome.setPreferrerOrientation), no rotations are registered anymore..

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue, the camera preview rotation works weird. What I ended up doing is using this package [native orientation](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) which provides the following API: `Stream<NativeDeviceOrientation> onOrientationChanged(useSensor: false)` which will trigger orientation changes even if you lock the screen using: `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()`

Basically in the init of your component:

```dart
_orientation = NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator()
        .onOrientationChanged(useSensor: true)
        .listen((event) {
      switch (event) {
        case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp:
        case NativeDeviceOrientation.unknown:
          _actualOrientation = DeviceOrientation.portraitUp;
          break;
        case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitDown:
          _actualOrientation = DeviceOrientation.portraitDown;
          break;
        case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
          _actualOrientation = DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft;
          break;
        case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
          _actualOrientation = DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight;
          break;
      }
    });
```

and then use the actual orientation to animate the icons or know the actual orientation of the captured image.

Remember to close the subscription on dispose `_orientation.cancel();`

Comment: Thanks man, I was looking for this kind of solution few days